# How to disable Excel built-in RibbonButton in Ribbon (Visual Designer)?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, ribbon, ribbon-control

Is it possible to set an excel 2010 built in RibbonButton to `enabled=false` from an excel **VSTO Add-In**?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample for Word, using Ribbon XML. I don't think you can use the ribbon designer for this. The same thing should work in Excel as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <commands>
    <command idMso="Font" enabled="false" />
  </commands>
</customUI>
```

This disables the *command*, which includes not just the buttons in the ribbon, but also any other way it could be triggered, e.g. through a keyboard shortcut.

If you want to do anything more specific you may have to re-create standard ribbons or ribbon groups. E.g. you can't just disable `Font` while leaving all other placements enabled. You would have to hide the standard Home tab and re-create it but with your specific changes (disabled, missing, etc.).